# Defining recursively expanded variable with same name as environment variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to lazily evaluate configuration option. I want to issue a `Make` error only if the variable is actually used (substituted).

Consider the following Makefile:

```
VAR = $(error "E")

NFS_DIR = NFS_DIR is $(VAR)

T = $(NFS_DIR) is 1

all:
    echo Test
```

If I run it with my environment (which has `/srv/nfs` value), the output is following:

```
➜  ~  make
echo Test
Makefile:3: *** "E".  Stop.
```

So the recursive definition acts like simple definition.

If I clear the environment, it works as expected:

```
➜  ~  env -i make  
echo Test
Test
```

I couldn't find any mention that recursively-expanded variable, when defined with same name as environment variable, will act like simply-expanded variable.

So the questions are:

1. Why the observed behavior?
2. How to implement the desired behavior?

Update: to clarify — I don't want to use `?=` since the options are configuration options I want them to come strictly from Makefile and not from environment.

Comment: The question appear to be extremely clear in the title but the actual request get lost in details so the only reply left it mostly unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable which is in the environment when make starts, will be exported to the environment of any command make runs (as part of a recipe, etc.)  In order for make to send the value of the variable to the command, make first has to expand it.  It's not acting like a simply-expanded variable.  It's just that running a command forces the expansion.

This is kind of a nasty side-effect but I'm not sure there's anything that can be done directly: this behavior is traditional and mandated by POSIX and lots of makefiles would break if it were changed.

You have two choices I can think of.  The first is to use the `unexport` make command to tell make to not send that variable in the command's environment.

The second is to change the name of the variable in make to something that is not a valid environment variable: make will only export variables whose names are legal shell variables (contain only alphanumeric plus `_`).  So using a name like `VAR-local` instead of `VAR` would do it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see which command causes the expansion of `$NFS_DIR`. I don't use it in any command

Comment: I didn't say it was used in a command.  I said it was in your environment.  If you run "env | grep NFS_DIR" from your shell prompt do you see it?  So when make starts it will import that value into a make variable and mark it to be exported to the commands that make runs.  Then you reset it in the makefile, but it's still marked as exported.  So when make wants to run a command it first needs to get the environment for the command, and it expands all the exported make variables.  That's when you see this.  Change the make variable name to something that is not a valid environment variable.

Comment: You said passing the variable to command causes the variable to be expanded. Which command were you talking about?

Comment: I said "send the value of the variable", in the context of creating an environment for the command.  The command in the example above is the "echo Test" command.  Make sees it needs for run that command.  Before it can run that command, it has to create the environment for that command.  Any make variable which is marked as exported, is added to the environment of the command, and to add it make has to expand the value of the variable.  All variables that make gets from its environment when it starts, are automatically marked exported.

Answer (score 0):

The question appear to be extremely clear in the title but the actual request get lost in details so the only other reply left it mostly unanswered. Directly answering to the question in the title, which is very interesting, to define a variable in a Makefile with same name as environment variable you can get its value with `printenv`:

```
PATH=${shell printenv PATH}:/opt/bin

echo:
    echo $(PATH)
```

Other techniques to achieve the same result without relying on evaluation with external commands are welcome.